# Fresh Ubuntu 16.04 install with Nvidia GTX 1070 is crashing

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 16.04, xorg, nvidia-geforce

I am one of the lucky people who received a *`MSI GTX 1070 Gaming X`* already, and so I decided to upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04 via a fresh install.

- The installation completed without any problems, and afterwards I installed the nvidia-367 driver from `ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`. The install worked with no problems, however when I boot into Ubuntu and use it, it will usually crash (black screen and immediate restart) without any prior indication.
- I already checked the `Xorg.log` and could not see any problems. It can be found [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/18033434/).
- I've already reinstalled Ubuntu **five times**, and tried both the `nvidia-367` and `nvidia-367-dev` packages.
- So far, no luck. I also disabled Secure Boot in my *Asus Sabertooth 99fx r2.0* 's BIOS, and updated it to the newest version (2501).

It still crashes at random intervals.

Thanks in advance!

Edit 2016-06-29:
I went back to 14.04.4 and intalled the nvidia-367 driver from the ppa above again. It created the same problem. 
I am stating to suspect my psu, as there is no mentioning of any shutdown procedure in the system log, it just reboots. Is this possible?

Comment: You can paste the `Xorg.log` at http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: How well does it work if you don't install proprietary drivers?

Comment: nouveau does not recognise the 1070 yet, so not really well. just basic 1024x768 resolution without the chance to change it. see: http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=nvidia-gtx-1070&num=1

Comment: The log does include a lot of "disconnected" messages... I have no idea what they mean though.

Comment: I guess for the PSU too.  Also, ensure all power cables are plugged.  Also, it could be the card him self. Have you tried on a other OS or computer ?